# How to assign multiple values to list of vectors in r?

Tags: r

I write the following code in r

```
Candidate <- vector(mode="list", length=3)
names(Candidate)<-c("Survivex","Survivey","Splitx")
Candidate[]<-0
   for(i in 1:10)
   {
      if(i%%2==0)
         Candidate["Survivex"]<-i
      else if(i%%5==0)
         Candidate["Survivey"]<-i
      else
         Candidate["Splitx"]<-i
   }
```

which gives the following result

```
Candidate
$Survivex
[1] 10

$Survivey
[1] 5

$Splitx
[1] 9
```

but my desired result is like

```
Candidate
$Survivex
[1] 2 4 6 8 10

$Survivey
[1] 5 10 

$Splitx
[1] 1 3 7 9
```

how can I modify my codes to get the required result

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the new results to the existing ones instead of replacing them, and
use double bracket extraction instead of single bracket subsetting.  For example,

```
Candidate <- vector(mode="list", length=3)
names(Candidate) <- c("Survivex", "Survivey", "Splitx")

for(i in 1:10)
{
  if(i %% 2 == 0)
     Candidate[["Survivex"]] <- c(Candidate[["Survivex"]], i)
  else if(i %% 5 == 0)
     Candidate[["Survivey"]] <- c(Candidate[["Survivey"]], i)
  else
     Candidate[["Splitx"]] <- c(Candidate[["Splitx"]], i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could work with `lapply()` and functions to get what you want.

```
Candidate <- lapply(1:3, function(j) unlist(do.call(cbind, lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  if (i %% 2 == 0) Candidate[[1]] <- i
  else if (i %% 5 == 0) Candidate[[2]] <- i
  else Candidate[[3]] <- i 
  if (i %% 5 == 0) Candidate[[2]] <- i
  return(Candidate)
}))[j, ]))

names(Candidate) <- nms
```

***Result***

```
> Candidate
$`Survivex`
[1]  2  4  6  8 10

$Survivey
[1]  5 10

$Splitx
[1] 1 3 7 9
```

***Data***

```
Candidate <- vector(mode="list", length=3)
nms <- names(Candidate) <- c("Survivex", "Survivey", "Splitx")
```